# WPF DataGridTextColumn dynamically code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a DataGrid dynamically after aprsing some tables.
For this I've created a DataGrid to be filled:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" BorderBrush="Transparent" 
    Background="#3FFFFFFF"  
    Padding="1" AlternatingRowBackground="#66CAE4FF" CanUserAddRows="False"  
    IsManipulationEnabled="True" ColumnHeaderHeight="30">
</DataGrid>
```

Content of the table will be a 2d array. Before I fill the table I need to create a header, because it will be the same for all table contents.
I save all my header-string in a list:

```
foreach (string headerItem in header)
{
    DataGridTextColumn head = new DataGridTextColumn { Header = headerItem };
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(head);
}
```

But my window is empty. I just see the grey ColumnHeader.

Comment: did you try to add Binding?

Comment: no,
I thought Binding is used, when having already content of the cells "under" the header. Can I use Binding irrespetiv of the content of table?

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the column names after the table filled, so you have the correct number of columns :

```
for (int i=0;i&lt;header.Length;i++)
  dataGrid.Columns[index].Header = header[index];
```

Comment: Works on my DataGrid - when do you try setting the header strings

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine for me.

I tried adding the headers on double-clicking the data-grid(just for illustration) and used this event handler in my sample MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var header = new List<string>() { "asdasd" };
        foreach (string headerItem in header)
        {
            DataGridTextColumn head = new DataGridTextColumn { Header = headerItem };
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(head);
        }
    }
```

[image: dynamic headers]

Comment: No, i just see some Header Column when I add them in .xaml